# Pushing a new branch

Tags: mercurial, push, branching-and-merging

I aborted a merge with a merge conflict when I realised that I had to push a new branch. So I tried

```
hg push --new-branch
```

but it says push creates new head. hg strip says abort: empty revision set. So I'm not sure what to do

Comment: Are there any changes you want to keep? if not,  "hg update -C -r ."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hg push --new-branch` allow push to create new **named branch** in remote repository (which was present only locally).

According to error, you tried to merge **2 heads** on the same named branch (have *anonymous branching*), and not committed mergeset means: "you still have multi-head branch" (check `hg heads` output), pushing of which is prohibited by default.